# React i18next - Don't show translations until request finished

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I am getting language info from backend. I would like to make the request to get language info, and then signalize to i18next that it can show translations. 
Currently, it shows the default language translations for a second, until the request finishes and I call `i18next.changeLanguage()`.

How would I achieve this ?

This is my config:

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import XHR from "i18next-xhr-backend";

 i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(XHR)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: "en-GB",
    keySeparator: false,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    },
    backend: {
      loadPath: "/locales/{{lng}}.json"
    }
  });
```

I am using the useTranslation hook to get the t function:

```
 const { t } = useTranslation();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In case of react-i18next make sure useSuspense is enabled or handle the ready state in HOCs or hooks yourself.

You need to wrap your root component with `Suspense` component to determine what should be rendered while translations are loading.

```js
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import RealApp from './App';
import Loading from './Loading';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import App from './App';

function Root(props) {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
        <Root />
      </I18nextProvider>
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

For more [info](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#not-using-suspense).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ready` flag from `useTranslation` hook to detect if your translation is ready or not:

```
const { t, ready } = useTranslation()
```

Then show a loading icon if it's not ready in the root component (App.tsx || App.jsx):

```
if (!ready) {
    return <LoadingIcon isCoverPage />;
  }
```

Please have a look at the usage of it in the following documentation link

[useTranslation hook](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook)